# Unshelved file needs resolve error

Tags: perforce

When i try to shelve a change

```
p4 shelve -r -c 1111111
```

it fails with errors:

```
<file x> - unshelved file for <user y> needs resolve
Shelve aborted -- fix problems then use 'p4 shelve -c 1111111'.
```

There used to be conflicts but they are resolved now, and `p4 resolve` says there are no files to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out specifying the force option solved the problem:
p4 shelve -c 1111111 -f

Answer (score 1):

What this is telling you is that *another* user (user y) has a pending resolve from that shelved revision.  Since you're replacing (or possibly removing?) that file from the shelf with the `-r` option, they might not be able to do their resolve and finish their unshelve operation.

Good lesson here is that if you do a `p4 unshelve` when you have local changes, make sure to follow it up with a `p4 resolve` quickly before the owner of the shelf deletes or changes it underneath you!  :)

Comment: there is no other user, "user y" is me